# Does the ScaleX scaleY makes the Width and height change?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Am working in flex 4 the sample mxml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600" >

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                trace(hgroup.width ,hgroup.height);
                hgroup.scaleX = 1.5;
                hgroup.scaleY = 1.5; 
                trace(hgroup.scaleX, hgroup.scaleY);
                trace(hgroup.width ,hgroup.height);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:HGroup id="hgroup" width="85%" height="85%" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">
        <s:Button click="button1_clickHandler(event)" label="Click to Scale"/>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:Application>
```

If i debug

on a first button click the trace shows like this

```
870 535
1.5 1.5
870 535
```

on second click of button the trace shows like this

```
580 356.6666666666667
1.5 1.5
580 356.6666666666667
```

on the perpendicular clicks it shows as like the second click

my question is does the scaleX scaleY affects the width height??

please guide me i need increase in width height perpendicular 
with the scaleX scaleY

Comment: Why don't you modify width and height properties, and evoid scale problems?

Comment: @gabitzish Thanks For your comment. but I need both scaling and width height to be increased simultaneously. the width and height needed to be increased when scaleX and scaleY increase. the width height needed for further computation say Scrollrect.

Comment: Mixing percent sizes with scale calls for all kinds of trouble. The layout manager will set the `HGroup` to 85% of the parent container, while applying a scale of 1.5. Not good. You should rather scale the button.

Comment: @bummzack I applied the static width height, then i applied the scaleX scaleY but unfortunately the width height seems to be same. This is the sample code but i need the same scenario in the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, scaling does affect width and height. I'm a little surprised that isn't reflected immediately in the third trace statement but my guess is it has something to do with the invalidation and redrawing of flex components. I double checked on a simple non-flex app and the properties for width and height updated immediately.

=============

Finally i got Answer the scaling will not change width height. but what the thing is i used the percent width height so it get reduced. I double checked with the static width height i does not get increased but when the width height increased the scaleX scaleY increases simultaneously.Keep this in the Mind

Thanks all for the support 
by Sudharsanan

~~~~Happy Coding~~~~~

Comment: ya what u said is correct. but please see that scaleX scaleY increases by 1.5 times but on the next trace the width reduces. please say why so.

Answer (score 1):

Scaling effects the width or height of the object you scaled.
The contents of hgroup ( aka myBTN )will be unchanged.
What would be the point of scaling something if it didn't get bigger or smaller

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
  trace( hgroup.width ,hgroup.height);//52 22
  trace( myBTN.width ,myBTN.height);//52 22
  hgroup.scaleX = 1.5;
  hgroup.scaleY = 1.5; 
  hgroup.validateNow()
  trace( hgroup.scaleX, hgroup.scaleY);//1.5 1.5
  trace( hgroup.width ,hgroup.height);//78 33 // notice the scaling changed the container
  trace( myBTN.width ,myBTN.height);//52 22 // here is where you see the sizes unchanged
}

<mx:Canvas id="hgroup" >
  <mx:Button id="myBTN" label="Click" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" />
</mx:Canvas>
```

And to answer HotN on why there isn't an immediate update is because this is a display object and as such will follow the uiComponent framework.
To make the changes immediately you have to call "validateNow" To update the display list instead of waiting for the next frame.

Comment: Hmmm but no effect in that, First click '1024 620
1.5 1.5
1024 620' second click '682.6666666666666 413.3333333333333
1.5 1.5
682.6666666666666 413.3333333333333' i think you r working in flex 3   even though my width height reduces in flex 4.

Comment: flex 3 or flex 4 it does not matter. once the scale is set to 1.5 the contents of hgroup in my example will not change width or height. clicking more and more will not change the scale anymore because the scale is 1.5 I really have no idea where you are getting your figures from. So please stop guessing and actually try the example.

Comment: Thanks for Your help. finally i got idea the scaling will not change width height. but what the thing is i used the percent width height so it get reduced. I got little confused that your canvas size has been increased 1.5 times. I double checked with the static width.